# discriminant of the division field of an elliptic curve

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\ell$ be a prime number. Let $\bar{\rho}$ be the representation of $Gal(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ on $E[\ell]$. Let $L:=\mathbb{Q}(E[\ell])=\bar{\mathbb{Q}}^{ker\bar{\rho}}$ be the field fixed by the kernel of $\bar{\rho}$ and $\Delta$ be the prime to $\ell$ part of the absolute discriminant $|\Delta_{L}|$. Is there an explicit relationship between $\Delta$ and the prime to $\ell$ part of the absolute discriminant of $E$. I'm mainly interested in the case when $E$ has semistable reduction with good reduction at $\ell$. For such an elliptic curve $E$, say we know that the absolute discriminant $|\Delta_E|$ is $\leq X$, can we prove an upper bound for $\Delta$ in terms of (some fixed power of) $X$.

There's an explicit relationship between the Artin conductor of the residual representation $\bar{\rho}_{E,\ell}$ and the conductor of $E$, but I'm not sure if this is helpful.

Comment: If $p>3$ has multiplicative reduction, then my guess is the following. If $\ell$ divides the Tamagawa number $c_p$, then $p$ is unramified in $L$. Otherwise the exponent of $p$ in $\Delta_L$ is $(\ell-1)/\ell$ times the degree of $L$. This is obtained using the Tate curve - if I am not mistaken. For $p=2$ and $3$ the bound will be larger, but again not directly linked to the number of components, which is the power in $\Delta_E$.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich Are you referring to the paper "Sur la p-differente du corps des points
de l-torsion des courbes elliptiques", by Cali and Kraus?

Comment: No, that paper is the harder case of $\ell=p$.

Comment: Thinking back about my guess above. I am quite certain now that this is correct also for $p=2$ and $3$. So for semistable curves the best bound should be $X^4$.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich There are 2 papers, one for $\ell=p$ and the other for $\ell\neq p$. Do you have a reference in mind for this statement, the paper I mentioned was the only one I was able to find.

Comment: Sorry about that. I wasn't aware of any of the two papers and even less so that there were two with very very identical names. The $\ell\neq p$ paper seems to tell you exactly what you want. The semistable case is easy enough that one doesn't need the paper.